# IOException for set operation in memcached in java

Tags: java, windows-xp, memcached, spymemcached

My java code is giving ioexception and memcache server reconnects when i try to set a key in memcache.i m using windows xp not linux..

Code :

```
public class Memcache implements Serializable  {

    MemcachedClient client;

    public static final int EXP_TIME = 10;
    public static final String KEY = "spoon";

    public static void main(String[] args)throws IOException{
        Memcache temp=new Memcache();
        Dummy dummy= new Dummy("Hello World");

        try {
           temp.client = new MemcachedClient(new InetSocketAddress("localhost", 11211));
        } catch (IOException e) {
           e.printStackTrace();
           System.err.println("connection problem");
        }
        temp.obj=temp.client.getAvailableServers();
        System.out.println(temp.obj);
        temp.obj1=temp.client.getUnavailableServers();
        System.out.println(temp.obj1);
        temp.client.add(KEY, EXP_TIME, dummy);
        Object myObject=temp.client.get(KEY);
        System.out.println(myObject);
        temp.client.delete(KEY);
    }
}
```

I debugged the code but when it reached set operation it gave IOException n disconnected.

code for dummy is:

```
import java.io.Serializable;

public class Dummy implements Serializable {
    String one;

    public Dummy(String one){
        this.one=one;
    }
}
```

stacktrace is:

```
2012-06-15 14:30:19.259 INFO net.spy.memcached.MemcachedConnection:  Added {QA sa=/10.2.200.104:11211, #Rops=0, #Wops=0, #iq=0, topRop=null, topWop=null, toWrite=0, interested=0} to connect queue
2012-06-15 14:30:19.274 INFO net.spy.memcached.MemcachedConnection:  Connection state changed for sun.nio.ch.SelectionKeyImpl@7cbde6
[/10.2.200.104:11211]
[]
2012-06-15 14:30:22.852 INFO net.spy.memcached.MemcachedConnection:  Reconnecting due to exception on {QA sa=/10.2.200.104:11211, #Rops=1, #Wops=0, #iq=0, topRop=Cmd: set Key: spoon Flags: 1 Exp: 10 Data Length: 76, topWop=null, toWrite=0, interested=1}
java.io.IOException: Disconnected unexpected, will reconnect.
    at net.spy.memcached.MemcachedConnection.handleReads(MemcachedConnection.java:452)
    at net.spy.memcached.MemcachedConnection.handleIO(MemcachedConnection.java:380)
    at net.spy.memcached.MemcachedConnection.handleIO(MemcachedConnection.java:242)
    at net.spy.memcached.MemcachedConnection.run(MemcachedConnection.java:833)
2012-06-15 14:30:22.852 WARN net.spy.memcached.MemcachedConnection:  Closing, and reopening {QA sa=/10.2.200.104:11211, #Rops=1, #Wops=0, #iq=0, topRop=Cmd: set Key: spoon Flags: 1 Exp: 10 Data Length: 76, topWop=null, toWrite=0, interested=1}, attempt 0.
2012-06-15 14:30:22.852 WARN net.spy.memcached.protocol.ascii.AsciiMemcachedNodeImpl:  Discarding partially completed op: Cmd: set Key: spoon Flags: 1 Exp: 10 Data Length: 76
2012-06-15 14:30:24.868 INFO net.spy.memcached.MemcachedConnection:  Reconnecting {QA sa=/10.2.200.104:11211, #Rops=0, #Wops=0, #iq=0, topRop=null, topWop=null, toWrite=0, interested=0}
2012-06-15 14:30:24.868 INFO net.spy.memcached.MemcachedConnection:  Connection state changed for sun.nio.ch.SelectionKeyImpl@113beb5
2012-06-15 14:30:31.665 INFO net.spy.memcached.MemcachedConnection:  Reconnecting due to exception on {QA sa=/10.2.200.104:11211, #Rops=1, #Wops=0, #iq=0, topRop=Cmd: get Keys: spoon Exp: 0, topWop=null, toWrite=0, interested=1}
java.io.IOException: Disconnected unexpected, will reconnect.
    at net.spy.memcached.MemcachedConnection.handleReads(MemcachedConnection.java:452)
    at net.spy.memcached.MemcachedConnection.handleIO(MemcachedConnection.java:380)
    at net.spy.memcached.MemcachedConnection.handleIO(MemcachedConnection.java:242)
    at net.spy.memcached.MemcachedConnection.run(MemcachedConnection.java:833)
2012-06-15 14:30:31.665 WARN net.spy.memcached.MemcachedConnection:  Closing, and reopening {QA sa=/10.2.200.104:11211, #Rops=1, #Wops=0, #iq=0, topRop=Cmd: get Keys: spoon Exp: 0, topWop=null, toWrite=0, interested=1}, attempt 0.
2012-06-15 14:30:31.665 WARN net.spy.memcached.protocol.ascii.AsciiMemcachedNodeImpl:  Discarding partially completed op: Cmd: get Keys: spoon Exp: 0
2012-06-15 14:30:33.680 INFO net.spy.memcached.MemcachedConnection:  Reconnecting {QA sa=/10.2.200.104:11211, #Rops=0, #Wops=0, #iq=0, topRop=null, topWop=null, toWrite=0, interested=0}
2012-06-15 14:30:33.680 INFO net.spy.memcached.MemcachedConnection:  Connection state changed for sun.nio.ch.SelectionKeyImpl@edf389
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception waiting for value
    at net.spy.memcached.MemcachedClient.get(MemcachedClient.java:1001)
    at net.spy.memcached.MemcachedClient.get(MemcachedClient.java:1018)
    at ballydev.Memcache.main(Memcache.java:39)
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Cancelled
    at net.spy.memcached.internal.OperationFuture.get(OperationFuture.java:103)
    at net.spy.memcached.internal.GetFuture.get(GetFuture.java:62)
    at net.spy.memcached.MemcachedClient.get(MemcachedClient.java:997)
    ... 2 more
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Cancelled
    ... 5 more
```

Comment: Do you have a stacktrace to spare?

Comment: Looks like a firewall / antivirus issue to me. Try disabling it.

Comment: i cant.. group policy...

Comment: May be i should try to close firewall on my 11211 port....

Comment: What memcached server do you use on Windows? How do you run it?

Comment: i downloaded the server from <http://splinedancer.com/memcached-win32/>... n i installed it by following the command given on that page.In services it shows that the memcached server is started...

Comment: This is quite old version, try this one: [memcached 1.4.5](http://blog.elijaa.org/index.php?post/2010/08/25/Memcached-1.4.5-for-Windows)

Answer (score 1):

To debug the issue, please try to telnet to the memcached from the server where the request originates. The memcached can refuse connection to other host if it is started explicitly  mentioning the ip address.

Comment: i tried telnet localhost 11211 command but  command prompt shows blank screen... the cursor just moves blank even if i type something in ...

Comment: no nothin comes up when i type any character on cmd... its returns to normal when i press enter...